# How to assign class property to point on Windows form variable

Tags: c#, winforms, class, reference, ref

I have class KeyWordsManager

```
public class KeyWordsManager
{
public Designation designation { get; set; }

public KeyWordsManager(ref Designation design)
{
this.designation=design;
}
}
```

And i have my windows form which have "global variable designation"

```
public partial class NewJob : Form
{
//some code
    private Designation newJobDesignation=new Designation();

 private void NewJob_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KeyWordsManager manager = new KeyWordsManager(ref newJobDesignation);
    }
}
```

The problem is when i want to modify newJobDesignation variable in my form, and when i try to set value to some textbox from KeyWordsManager class, it isnt changed , as if it doesnt reference to object in form class.

I have same scheme but instead of my custom Designation class i used ComboBox and is working well. 
Does someone know what is the problem? I though ref keyword would solve the problem but it didnt. Did i reference it good or maybe there is problem outside this part of code

Comment: That's not going to work. C# doesn't support ref fields. There are ways to achieve this, but why do you need this? why do you assign `newJobDesignation` a new instance and not modifying the existing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure of what you are trying to do, but the following function creates a new local KeyWordsManager that goes out of scope (eventually garbage collected) when the function exits.

```
private void NewJob_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   KeyWordsManager manager = new KeyWordsManager(ref newJobDesignation);
}
```